# Is there anyway to sort incoming data from StreamBuilder?

Tags: firebase, flutter, sorting, listview, stream-builder

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Listings').snapshots();
```

I am using this stream.

And i have streambuilder like this.

```
Flexible(
              child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: _usersStream,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text('Error');
                  }
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Text("Loading");
                  }
                  return ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                      Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                      String start_location=data['start_location'];
                      String end_location=data['end_location'];
                      String date=data['date'];
                      String time=data['time'];
                      String price=data['price'];
                      String name_surname=data['name_surname'];
                      String userId=data['user_id'];

                      String coord=data['coord'];
                      var splitted=coord.split('/');
                      for(int i=0; i<splitted.length-1; i++){
                        String x = splitted[i];
                        var splitted2=x.split('-');
                        double result=calculateDistance(widget.place_latlng.latitude, widget.place_latlng.longitude, double.parse(splitted2[0]), double.parse(splitted2[1]));
                        
                        if(result<1 && start_location!= widget.placename){
                          print("Found!");
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: (){
                              //onTap func
                            },
                            child: buildTripCard(
                              context,
                              start_location: start_location,
                              end_location: end_location,
                              date: date,
                              time: time,
                              price: price,
                              name_surname: name_surname,
                              userId: userId,
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                      }
                      return Container();
                    }).toList(),

                  );
                },
              ),
            )
```

I put into the incoming data to calculateDistance function. It returns double value (result).If that value less than 1, it shows in ListView. What i want to do is, sort Data which shows in listView order by result value.
How can i reach list that i created with .toList() method?

Answer (score 0):

Sort data by chaining into stream. The below example takes all photos, which title starts with p. Converting Future to Stream is just for demonstration.

```
Stream<List<Photo>> photos() {
  return Stream.fromFuture(
    http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos'))
  ).map((r) => parsePhotos(r.body))
   .map((list) => list.where((p) => p.title.startsWith('p')).toList());
}
```

Then use `ListView.builder` to render the final list.

```
StreamBuilder<List<Photo>>(
  stream: photos(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return const Center(
        child: Text('An error has occurred!'),
      );
    } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
      final photos = snapshot.data!;
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: photos.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text(photos[index].title);
        },
      );
    } else {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }
  }
```